# Loop through all possible ipv4 addresses in c#

Tags: c#, hash, ip, sha1

Currently this is what I have:

```
            for (int a = number; a < 255; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 255; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < 255; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = 0; d < 255; d++)
                        {
                            string ip = String.Concat(a, '.', b, '.', c, '.', d);
                            string _id = TruncateLongString(Hash(ip), 20);
                            if (_id == "AE18D602C836D7EAD1F8")
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ip);
                                Thread.Sleep(3600000);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But this is very slow and take absolute ages. Is there any other way to do this, preferably in a much faster way? Also, the reason for this is cracking sha1 hash, me and another person are trying to figure out how a person managed to crack the hash (_id) for an ip in about three seconds. Fyi the hash also has a salt, which is known. Also, if your wondering, `number` is the number I have given the thread to use, going up from 1 to about 40. Also we have no idea what coding language the person used, but we guessed c# for its speed and because we knew some of it, but there's probably something much faster.

Comment: A first idea is to use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate a+b+c+d, or **string interpolation**. You can check what is the better with a thing like a `Stopwatch`... Keep in mind that console writes are slow too... so try to put it out of loops using a `List<string>` or a `HashSet` that may be better, that you join at the end for example, or a simple string using `NewLine` in your case. Also you can try `IPAddress` class.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` will be the boottleneck here. And nothe that this will produce about 4.000.000.000 lines.

Comment: Both are bottlenecks (the string assignment and `Console.WriteLine`): see, e.g., [How come for loops in C# are so slow when concatenating strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50071096/7444103). -- You really don't want to do this. It's also quite useless.

Comment: Like Jimi mentioned, both string manipulation and console print are bottlnecks. I am pretty sure no real world problem require iterating through all ipv4 addresses. May be if the op gives more info on that, we might be able to help better.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`IPAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress?view=net-5.0) class for this?

Comment: it may have excluded IP address ranges that it is not interested in, local networks, etc.

Comment: @RufusL The problem is I don't really know how I would use the `IPAddress` class for this case.

Comment: I think that in a reasonable time it is impossible to calculate 4 billion hashes, so either the hashes were already ready or the person guessed :)

Comment: I think it is impossible to calculate one million hashes in 1 millisecond

Comment: @Stanislav I generated a hash using `255.255.255.255` as an ip and the person still got it in 3 seconds. Either somehow the person got the first two numbers using the _id witch is half the sha1, which should be impossible, or he had some huge file of some sort, which is still insanely large.

Comment: if the hash selection time does not change, it is similar to O(1) access to the collection element.

Comment: It can use cascading tables or trees to store hash matches to an IP address. Add the prefix to TruncateLongString($"Prefix_{IP}")

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the number of method Console.WriteLine calls. Use Parallel.For and an array with generated IP addresses. Do not use well-known data to generate hashes, or add the prefix " some_{Ip}"

```
var array = new string[255];
for (int a = 1; a < 256; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++)
    {
        var prefB = String.Concat(a.ToString(), ".", b.ToString(), "."); 
        for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
        {
            var prefC =  String.Concat(prefB, c.ToString(), "."); 
            Parallel.For(0, 256, d =>
            {
                array[d] = String.Concat(prefC, d.ToString());
                
            });
            
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, array));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the console output is most the critical point, why not put the writeline at the end outside the main loop? Using a HashSet (or any more optimized collection for this case)?

Comment: The maximum size of the collection is limited to ~2 billion values, the number of IP addresses is ~4 billion, you need to make an array of arrays

Comment: The author changed the question after I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another little notice: IPv4 addresses are 1 byte in size - so they go from 0 - 255, and not 254.

So the for-loop would have to be adjusted:

```cs
for (int a = 0; a < 256; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < 256; d++) {
```

*(Sorry to give the notice as an answer, but I can't comment yet)*

Answer (score 0):

First, there are UInt32.MaxValue possible IPv4 addresses, but not all IPv4 values are actually [in use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks). So you could skip ranges that will never be mapped.

I'd guess that it should be possible to compute all 4 billion possible hashes in about 3 CPU hours. If you are using a single constant salt, it's possible that an attacker could spend the time to pre-compute the complete table to quickly lookup the result. 4 billion * 10 byte answers is only 40GB, quite easy to store on a HD.